# MaxScript - object properties at specific frame

Tags: maxscript

how do I get an objects transform matrix at a specific frame without setting the sliderTime to that frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "at time" context, also take a look at the  coordsys context!

```
local objTM = at time 20f in coordsys world selection[1].transform
```